# how to achieve the paired device's pin code as bluetooth is connecting?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Base on android 9.0,as the bluetooth is connecting,it will display a six bits pin code,and i need to achieve the code in my apps.

the paired pin code is created by android system automatically,i don't know how to achieve it,or it can't.

Thanks in advance,
scoket